# How to add additional param in maven dependencies pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I'm looking for a way to add additional param  in dependencies of pom.xml. This info I will read it from maven plugin jar.

EX:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
            <some-param>val</some-param>
        </dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `maven-4.0.0.xsd` clearly forbids adding any non-`dependency`-related elements. What exact problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to find the dependencies which are in-house(```internal```) built and which are 3rd party(```external```).

Comment: I guess you can simply find them by using `groupId`.

Comment: for internal level projects there are problem in ```groupId```. It sometimes matches with external one

Comment: @NehaNidhi If you use the same groupId internally which are already used externally that's the issue... and no supplemental information is possible as already mentioned.... and can you elaborate more in detail what the real problem is? Don't you know the parts which are done internally?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot add additional XML elements.